# ModalDialog and Editing values inside shiny module

Tags: shiny, module

In a shiny application, I try to add the possibility for the users to edit the values inside a table.
Multiple users could update values inside the table, maybe at the same time and for the same columns.

I use the DT package 0.23 and R 4.0.4.

I try to adapt this code (https://github.com/jienagu/DT-Editor/blob/master/server.R) inside module, but it does not work.

What is my mistake ?

```
     ddUI <- function(id){
          ns <- NS(id)
          
          tagList(
            tabBox(width = 12
                   ,tabPanel("", br(),
                               fluidRow(column(4,
                                      HTML('<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example" style = "padding:10px">'),
                                      tags$head(tags$style(".butt4{background-color:#4d1566;} .butt4{color: #e6ebef;}")),
                                      div(style="display:inline-block;width:30%;text-align: center;",actionButton(inputId = ns("edit.row"),label = "Edit", icon = icon("plus"), class="butt4") ),
                                      HTML('</div>') 
                                      )),
                               column(12,dataTableOutput(ns("Main_table_trich"))),
                               
                               tags$script("$(document).on('click', '#Main_table_trich button', function () {
                                             Shiny.onInputChange('lastClickId',this.id);
                                             Shiny.onInputChange('lastClick', Math.random()) });")
                    )
    )
    }
    
    ddserver <- function(id){
      moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
 ### interactive dataset 
  vals_trich<-reactiveValues()
  vals_trich$Data<-readRDS("note.rds")

  #### render DataTable part ####
  output$Main_table_trich<-renderDataTable({
    DT=vals_trich$Data
    datatable(DT,selection = 'single',
              escape=F) })

        ### edit button
        observeEvent(input$edit.row,{
          showModal(
            if(length(input[[paste0("Main_table_trich_rows_selected")]])>=1 ){
              modalDialog(
                fluidPage(
                  h3(strong("Modification"),align="center"),
                  hr(),
                  dataTableOutput(NS(id,'row_modif')),
                  actionButton(NS(id,"save_changes"),"Save changes"),
    
                  tags$script(HTML(paste0("$(document).on('click', '.save_changes', function () {
                                 var list_value=[]
                                 for (i = 0; i < $( '.new_input' ).length; i++)
                                 {
                                 list_value.push($( '.new_input' )[i].value)
                                 }
                                 Shiny.onInputChange('", NS(id,"newValue"), "', list_value) });")))
                  ), size="l" )
                  
            }else{
              modalDialog(
                title = "Warning",
                paste("Please select the row that you want to edit!" ),easyClose = TRUE
              )
            }
            
          )
        })
        
        is.Date <- function(x) {
          inherits(x, c("Date", "POSIXt"))
        }
    
        output$row_modif<-renderDataTable({
          selected_row=input[[paste0("Main_table_trich_rows_selected")]]
          old_row=vals_trich$Data[selected_row,]
          row_change=list()
          for (i in colnames(old_row))
          {
            if (is.numeric(vals_trich$Data[[i]]))
            {
              row_change[[i]]<-paste0('<input class="new_input" value= ','"',old_row[[i]],'"','  type="number" id=new_',i,' ><br>')
            }
            else if( is.Date(vals_trich$Data[[i]])){
              row_change[[i]]<-paste0('<input class="new_input" value= ','"',old_row[[i]],'"',' type="date" id=new_  ',i,'  ><br>')
            }
            else
              row_change[[i]]<-paste0('<input class="new_input" value= ','"',old_row[[i]],'"',' type="textarea"  id=new_',i,'><br>')
          }
          row_change=as.data.table(row_change)
          setnames(row_change,colnames(old_row))
          DT=row_change
          DT
        },escape=F,options=list(dom='t',ordering=F,scrollX = TRUE),selection="none" )
    
        observeEvent(input$newValue,
                     {
                       newValue=lapply(input$newValue, function(col) {
                         if (suppressWarnings(all(!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(col)))))) {
                           as.numeric(as.character(col))
                         } else {
                           col
                         }
                       })
                       DF=data.frame(lapply(newValue, function(x) t(data.frame(x))))
                       colnames(DF)=colnames(start.df$data)
                       vals_trich$Data[input[[paste0("Main_table_trich_rows_selected")]],]<-DF
                       removeModal()
                     }
        )
  })
}
```

Thank you for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a module, the id of your table is *not* `Main_table_trich`: it is the string in the output of `ns("Main_table_trich")`. That is to say, if `YOURID` is the `id` you use, then the id of your table is `YOURID-Main_table_trich`.

So you have to use this id in the JavaScript code. The **glue** package is convenient to achieve that:

```r
tags$script(
  glue::glue(
    "$(document).on('click', '#[id]-Main_table_trich button', function() {
       Shiny.onInputChange('lastClickId',this.id);
       Shiny.onInputChange('lastClick', Math.random());
    });", 
    .open = "[", .close = "]")  
)
```